# cant enable theme in multisite

Tags: multisite, themes

Has anyone met this problem :

When I click `Network enable` on any theme: 
[image]

then after page is reloaded, the same thing happens - the theme is not enabled, and there is still "Network Enable" . 
I have deleted all plugins, but still same problem.

Comment: Did you saved the `rewrite_rule` when you initiated multisite ?

Comment: yes. sub-sites at this moment are working with the default twentysixteen, but  even twentysixteen is showing "Network enable" in mainsite.

Comment: found solution and answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I've found that, in `wp-sitemeta` DB table, `allowedthemes` record value was incorrectly serialized (dont know why) and there was `a:4` (instead of `a:3`, because actual length of array was: 3 values of **`s:`**)

`a:4:{s:13:"twentysixteen";b:1;  s:5:"meris";b:1;  s:8:"my_theme";b:1;}`

I  changed `a:4` to `a:3` and it worked. (also, make sure there is no more `allowedthemes` rows in `wp-sitemeta` table)

Comment: Glad that you've solved your own question, be sure to click the checkmark after two two to indicate that this question has been resolved

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I think that if i make my own answer checkmarked, i will get a penalty for Bounty-boosting. Am i right?

Comment: Nope, you won't get any reputation for solving your own answer, and we actually [encourage people to answer their own questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I've done it a few time myself.

Comment: This just helped me fix a similar problem.  Thanks!